# What is the most readable way to display a U.S. phone number?

Tags: formatting, phone-numbers, data-display

What is the best format for a full 10-digit U.S. phone number in terms of readability, accessibility, and overall ease-of-use?

A few examples:

- (800) 555-1234
- (800)555-1234  (no space after the area code)
- 800-555-1234
- 800 555-1234

Personally I think the first option is best but I can't pinpoint *why*. I also wonder whether the inclusion of the parentheses adds helpful cues or causes cognitive overload and/or distraction.

The target audience is the general public and the users are almost all American residents. The phone numbers are normally displayed on a web site alongside other data such as a street address.

Many of these numbers were entered by the user and are being displayed back for verification purposes. The users are allowed to enter the number in any format; on the server, we strip all spaces and punctuation and store only the 10 digits.

Comment: This may not be relevant to your application but your examples don't have the 'trunk prefix' which would be something like **1-** (800)-555-1234. If users are doing the phone entry you might want to watch out for that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trunk_prefix

Comment: @jmathew otherwise known as the county code; its absence always irks me

Comment: In some applications, such as resume headings, alternative formatting such as `860.740.4500` is easier to read.

Comment: Avoid the debate entirely and use the [standard way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers#United_States.2C_Canada.2C_and_other_NANP_countries).

Comment: @user1717828 I don't actually find that easier to read... At a glance, it's nearly identical to an IP address. I know you said "in some applications", but I personally dislike when people try to make a phone number look hip or trendy. Clarity should always trump style.

Comment: Is the intended audience national or international?

Comment: @cat Not exactly the same for a local audience. In North America the 1 prefix also plays the role of trunk number when dialling long-distance, the same as 0 at the beginning of phone numbers in Europe. So North Americans always dial 1 800... But never 011 (the international exit code) then 1 800...

Comment: @EJP That article says `The traditional formatting convention for phone numbers is (NPA) NXX-XXXX` but  the `format can be written NPA-NXX-XXXX, or as 1-NPA-NXX-XXXX` and `Sometimes the stylized format NPA.NXX.XXXX is seen`. So basically that link says "do whatever you want"

Comment: I'm tempted to say you should store and display exactly what the user entered, the user probably know better than you do how to display their own number. As it stands your system is almost certainly broken for some non-north-american numbers

Comment: It depends. Are we talking about a number as part of contact information on a website, email footer, business card or advertisement (print, TV, …)? Or are we talking about a smartphone calling app?

Comment: With option 1, you should use a thin space after the closing parenthesis, if that's feasible.

Comment: Periods. 800.555.1234

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I agree with you that the first is best.

Good UX is largely about reducing the cognitive load of a user. `(###) ###-####` is **a format that, [in North America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan#Modern_plan), is unique to phone numbers**, so I know as soon as I see the format that this is a phone number.

At first glance, if I just see {several numbers} {hyphen} {several numbers}... well, this could be a social security number, postal code, credit card number, phone number, etc. It would make me have to inspect the format closer, read a label, or evaluate the context in which the number is being displayed to determine its meaning.

Remove as much cognitive load from the user as possible.

*Use the visually distinctive `(###) ###-####` format.*

Comment: Also, Canadian numbers and Mexican numbers

Comment: @CanadianLuke True, I didn't word that correctly. I should have said that "In the US, this format is only used for phone numbers."

Comment: That would be more accurate, yes

Comment: Sorry if I offended you, _Canadian_ Luke!

Comment: It wasn't something I took offence to, we just like being thorough on Stack Exchange

Comment: I've come to dislike using parentheses around area codes.  It made sense when the way phone numbers were used was typically to dial only the exchange code and subscriber number, and "long distance" calls (between different area codes) required a special "escape code" prefix followed by the area code.  Now that the digit groups (within a country) always all appear together, marking that one group as distinct seems archaic.  I almost never have any trouble distinguishing phone numbers, SSNs, zip codes, credit card numbers, software registration codes, GPS coordinates, UUIDs, etc.

Comment: @Polyergic: I suggest that you describe as "was typically" is in fact "is typical" for most people, most of the time.  And so the conventional (xxx) xxx-xxxx works perfectly well, far better than the annoying xxx.xxx.xxxx which I always see as an internet address at first glance.

Comment: @jamesqf: Maybe for the minority still using landlines in sparsely pop ulated areas.  On modern phones there's usually no dialing at all, and no "long distance" other than international; even with landlines, some densely populated areas have to dial 10 digits.  But I agree about not using dots, I don't think I'd see it as an IP4 address, but to treat the area code like the exchange & subscriber numbers I use the ###-###-#### format.

Comment: On similarities with the all-hyphen version:  social security numbers are `xxx-xx-xxxx`

Comment: @Izkata Yes, and that's quite close to xxx-xxx-xxxx. In my answer, I included ellipsis to emphasize that _the prefix in question_ (numbers, hyphen, numbers) is less distinct of a format than parentheses, numbers, parentheses, etc.

Comment: @maxathousand I was just adding an example that was much closer than the non-phone-number examples given

Comment: @Polyergic: I don't know about 'minority', but the 7 vs 10 digit dialing does apply to cell phones - all the examples I gave were cell.  I've no great experience of densely populated areas (for which I'm thankful), but I suspect that 7 digit would still work for numbers in the same area code.   Of course literally 'dialling' is pretty well gone (though I do have a rotary dial phone on my kitchen wall - that came with the house, and worked up until I ditched the land line), but one must enter the number somehow.

Comment: In most of the larger urban areas within the United States, ten digit dialing is now the norm.  I know that here in Florida, seeing a number with only seven digits would be seen as both confusing and archaic, with the separated area code only slightly less so.

Answer (score 10):

Although option 1 is used most often, I would argue that

- the concept of an "area code" is pretty much deprecated by cell phones.  Now we simply have 10-digit phone numbers.
- many areas of the United States (and, I'm pretty sure, all cell phones) mandate 10-digit dialing, so the idea that the first three digits might be optional is also outdated.

For these two reasons, I would go for option 3, 800-555-1212, as the forward-looking choice for displaying a phone number.

Comment: The second point is not true in general, though it might (appear to) be of large urban areas that have several area codes (overlays, in telephone parlance).  I can dial any number in my area code (which covers most of one of the larger US states) from my cell phone using 7 digits - including, interestingly enough, my former neighbors who now live in a neighboring state, but kept their old phone numbers.

Comment: I honestly don't know.  My area requires 10-digit dialing, and my cell phone requires 10-digit dialing.  I know that cell phones emphatically do not use 1- before the area code.  I thought that, for that reason, cell phones require 10-digit dialing.

Comment: Every few months, I get a call from this elderly lady on her land-line, attempting to call her financial institution's toll-free number, 877-ABC-DEFG. My phone number is (XYZ) 877-ABCD, and XYZ is also her area code; I have to remind her each time that she needs to dial 1 first. Based on this, I would recommend either Option 1, or 1-800-555-1212 as an alternative form of Option 3, if that is preferred over the uses of parentheses.

Comment: "The first three digits of your 10-digit cell phone number indicates where you lived in 2007."

Comment: @hymie I disagree.  My memories from working at a cell phone company's national call center stated that 10 digit dialing was required in some areas, and 11 digit dialing was required in some (fewer) areas.

Comment: It really is just a 10-digit code now. I'm in Oregon where one code covers more than half the state. You still have to specify the code because there are so many out of state cell users. The parenthetical notation is a relic of bygone days.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest using the E.123 number unless your audience is purely USA based.
That way, us poor internationals don't have to guess about how to call a number.

+1 800 555 1234 since then it'll work on every phone, worldwide*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.123

Bitter experience of working for multiple USA based companies who have large address Exchange address books of pure 'USA' numbers... a joy.

(* assuming it can dial a +, of course. Welcome to the 21st century.)

Comment: +1 for the +1 (haha). as an ignorant american who has never needed to place an international call, i've always wondered whether the plus sign needed to be dialed or whether it's strictly decorational (like the parentheses in domestic numbers).

Comment: Given my engineer-mindset, I'm certainly in favour of this format, however, one has to note that many people sadly have no idea how to enter the "+" on their phone...

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow. The "+1" means "whatever your country uses to indicate that you're making an international call". For most countries, that's 00. The North American Numbering plan (USA, Canada, Mexico, ...) uses 001, for some reason.

Comment: On a mobile phone, which is what most people are using these days, just holding the 0 key for about 2 seconds puts the + in for you. @TRiG is right, the 00 / 001 is another half standard that most countries did one way but others did differently. Sigh...

Another advantage of putting all your numbers in your own address book with the + is that when you travel, you can still call people without having to figure out what the local country calling conventions are.

Comment: I believe that France originally used 19. They've now switched to 00, but I think 19 still works. @PaulHargreaves.

Answer (score 9):

**Option 1** has the following characteristics, making it the preferred choice:

**It's Conventional**

The Wikipedia page for "[National conventions for writing telephone numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers#United_States.2C_Canada.2C_and_other_NANP_countries)" states:

> The traditional formatting convention for phone numbers is (NPA)
>   NXX-XXXX, where NPA is the area code and NXX-XXXX is the subscriber
>   number

This is probably why you feel it's the right choice - *you see it everywhere*.

**It's readable**

Is it any more readable than options 3 or 4? That's arguable, but the ease with with Option 1 can be scanned/parsed, combined with it's conventionality, make it the right option to go with.

There are lots of ways you can play with the the styling of a telephone number, but my advice here is that **when you've got a strong and functional convention, don't mess with it.**

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt go to the bible of all publishing; the U.S. Government style manual.  This is used by all (almost all) publishers, and is the basis for all printing in the U.S.  They show a format of 555-555-5555.

Usually in programming an input form, it will show (555)555-5555 to make it easier to enter the numbers.  I prefer this on all business cards and forms.

Ref: https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2016/pdf/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2016.pdf